# Tableau and Cortana Integration

Tags: bigdata, tableau-api, powerbi, cortana-intelligence

Similar to using cortana cards to show powerbi visualisations, Is there any way to make tableau work with cortana intelligence suite? Searched a lot in internet but couldn't find a single piece of useful information. Any references or a workflow to make it work is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Tableau doesn't support cortana.But soon you may expect NLP but as of now no support for cortana.